# Intel HAXM install failure in Windows 1903

Tags: windows, android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

I've been using Android Studio with the built in HAXM emulator for a while. I updated my windows version to 1903, build 18362.145 and HAXM was removed from the SDK manager. When trying to install I get this error message:

```
Unable to install Intel HAXM
/dev/kvm is not found.
Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux distro 
has working KVM module.
```

I know that in windows, Hyper-V will stop HAXM from being installed, but it is disabled. I also found it very strange that it said I need a KVM module as that is a Linux Kernel based virtualisation technology. The first thing I did when I updated was enable Linux Subsystem for Windows. I have since disabled since I beleived it was the cause. That did not work. VT-x is enabled in my BIOS. I disabled Windows Snadbox as well, as enabling it was also something I did before attempting to run an emulator. Thanks for any help in this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After alot of research I came across this discussion related to VirtualBox. Regardless of that, the solution fixed all of my virtual machines. The entire page is [here](https://discuss.erpnext.com/t/virtualbox-wont-run-raw-mode-unavailable-courtesy-of-hyper-v/34541/17). I recommend you read the link, but basically you need to turn off windows hypervisor service from the command prompt with this command...

> bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off